# Typescript abstract method from generic: "class defines instance member property but extended class defines it as instance member function"

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given the following ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgHgDEEcAPCHAOwBMMAKASgQF4A+BANwHsBLKtgbwCwAKARiEABwCuIZN1gJQkGPAQB9NbGDJkGgFwICAbhEBfESIgBPCTgQBhbcgDK3AOYVgEKVHwAVNiYEIVFxBgM-E1CxWnZtKRwI+gMuXijzYREUNAwCTk48AOIyShosXDxHHVcPLx9-FgERcUkZOQUNLR0NcIRI5vFpWXl1TSceuOQEpIQUnioolqH20a7dNVj4nAB+GZCWlt9vKAoOLcXxDNMgA)):

```
abstract class Base<F extends () => void> {
    public abstract __call__: F;
}

type CallSignature<T> = {
    (): T;
    (value: T): void;
}

class Foo<T> extends Base<CallSignature<T>> {
    public __call__(): T;
    public __call__(value: T) : void;
    public __call__(value?: T) {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
Class 'Base<CallSignature<T>>' defines instance member property '__call__', but extended class 'Foo<T>' defines it as instance member function.(2425)
```

How can I specify that `__call__` in `Base` is meant to be a method, whilst still having its definition come from `T` (e.g. allowing an arbitrary signature including overloads)?

Note that `Base` is not allowed to refer directly to `CallSignature`, as this will be a different interface for different subclasses (hence why it is passed as `F`).

Also, the point of this question is that `Base` is meant to be in charge of what interface `Foo` needs to implement, even if Foo passes a generic that customises this in some way.

Comment: Overload are a bit of a hack in Typescript I would say, so I kinda doubt it's possible to pass a list of overload signatures through a generic type…

Comment: Why does the abstract class need to be generic if the only intent is to require a public method named `__call__` with no constrained signature? Does something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NnlaxW) work? If so, I can write up an answer. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jsejcksn this is a simplified example, for the purposes of this question assume that `Callable` may be coming from somewhere else and that `Base` may additionally be doing other things with it, including mutating the signature in some way. Right now I am specfically wanting to know if there is any way to specify the type of a method like this without typescript thinking that it now has to be a property. I've encountered this problem a few times now, not just with abstract methods, so I would like to know if there is a way to solve this.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75430614/typescript-abstract-method-from-generic-class-defines-instance-member-property?noredirect=1#comment133093610_75430614) @SystemParadox In that case, please update the question with a [mre] that represents the issue — including all applicable details and constraints.

Comment: I have updated the example to hopefully make it a bit clearer and less confusing.

Comment: This appears to be known issue, but may be fixed someday: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51261

Answer (score 0):

Instead of referencing the type of the `__call__` method, you can recreate it with the `Parameters` and `ReturnType` helpers.

```js
abstract class Base<T extends { __call__: () => void }> {
    public abstract __call__(...args: Parameters<T['__call__']>): ReturnType<T['__call__']>;
}

interface Callable<T> {
    __call__(): T;
    __call__(value: T): void;
}

class Foo<T> extends Base<Callable<T>> {
    public __call__(): T;
    public __call__(value: T) : void;
    public __call__(value?: T) {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works pretty well for a single type, but I'm not sure how well it works for overloads. I seem to get `__call__(value: T): T`?

Comment: Unfortunatly last I checked overloads don't work with `Parameters` and `ReturnType`. You'd still need to (re)declare all the overloads you want in `Foo`